# Keyboard punctuation

Tags: updates, settings, keyboard, text-input, text-prediction

I just updated my phone (Galaxy S3) and I don't like the new way auto prediction works, it keeps trying to predict the next word instead of giving me quick access to the punctuation. Does any one know if there is a way to have the auto prediction just give you a list of punctuation once you hit the space bar instead of trying to guess the next word?

When I originally got my phone last year when ever I finished texting a word and hit the space bar, the auto prediction bar would show all my punctuation and that was great. Than I did an update a several months ago, and the auto prediction started giving me next word predictions instead, the only way I could find around that was to double tab the space bar, than hit backspace/delete, and that would allow my auto prediction to once again show the punctuation available. It was a few extra clicks but at least it was still quick access to punctuation and didn't slow down the flow to much. But with this latest update auto prediction only seems to give word suggestions, I can't find anyway to make it show me punctuation. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks all.

Comment: You might try a different keyboard.  [Hacker's keyboard's](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) (my preferred keyboard) autocomplete seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have a galaxy Note 2. I opened a new message and at the top of the screen is a keyboard symbol. I pulled down the screen to then be able to "choose input method" which I tapped on. I then tapped "set up input methods" and tapped the settings icon next to "Samsung keyboard" which then allowed me to de-select predictive text. I've now been able to customise my settings a little.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google keyboard turn off Next-word suggestion option in settings. This way you will get the bar back after finishing each word.